# why use log operation in shannon capacity?

Tags: computer-networks

In shannon capacity, it uses log operation.

> bandwidth * log<sub>2</sub>(1 + SNR)

Why they use log operation instead of just using SNR?

Comment: Shannon capacity is not an arbitrary expression that Shannon came up with. It measures something. The expression you mention results from calculating the Shannon capacity of a particular channel.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_capacity, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_capacity#Example_application

Comment: If I give 3 apples to 4 friends I have given out 3x4=12 apples. Why do we use 3x4 instead of 3+4?